# Biggest inferior bound in a map using STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, maps

Using the code below I could find the lowest superior bound for a certain value. How could I do the same thing but for the biggest inferior bound?

```
double Sup(double const x) const {
    //Lower bound: first element that is greater-or-equal.
    map<double,double>::iterator it=MapCurve.lower_bound(x);
    if (it!=MapCurve.end()) {
        return it->first;
    } else {
        --it;
        return it->first;
    }           
}
```

say you have these key values in the map : 0.2 | 0.7 | 1.3 | 2.4 | 5.1

Sup(1.2) gives 1.3

now i want and Inf function such that Inf(1.2) will give 0.7. how could I do this?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]: we can't guess how `MatCurve` was defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower_bound(x)` give the first element that doesn't go before x (that is >=). You want the previous element.

```
auto it = MapCurve.lower_bound(x);
if (it == MapCurve.begin()) {
  // No element less than x in the map.
  // throw error or return error code.
}
--it;
return it->first;
```

Comment: `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` both give a greater value, the difference is that one of them gives a stricly greater value. so your code still gives a greater value. my question is about smaller values

Comment: Try it out. The idea is to take the previous element, which is strictly lower than x (if it exists).